# Xcode CommandLineTools installed but still getting the error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Monterey

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools, xcode-select

I have MacOS Montery 12.3.1 and I have already installed Xcode and installed CommandLineTools long time ago.
I have Xcode-select version:

xcode-select version 2395.

Now, while trying to install heroku cli I got the error:

Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Monterey.
Install the Command Line Tools: `xcode-select --install`

But the command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

the installation now would last 89 hours and it tries to download 15GB which can't be right...

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

I tried this but the second command throws the error:

> xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

the folder CommandLineTools is in that directory... I am clueless. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to deinstall Xcode(and everything related) and Homebrew. After reinstalling Xcode the CommandLineTools got installed with Homebrew and are working fine again.